# How can I fix this error TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting this error in my program and I have no idea how to fix it. Here's where the error comes.

```
def check_file(): 
       for read in range(6):
       length = len(linecache.getline('status.py', read))
       f = linecache.getline('status.py', read)[0:length-1]
       print (f)
       if read >= 6:
           print("5")
       else:
           file[read-1][1] = f
   return file

def change_state(change_till, state): # changes tills' status
    global file
    data = ''
    status = check_file()
    status[change_till-1][1] = state
    file = open('status.py', 'w')
    file.write(status[0][1]+'\n'+status[1][1]+'\n'+status[2][1]+'\n'+status[3][1]+'\n'+status[4][1])
    file.close()
    return state
```

I run the code and this error comes up

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rhysj\OneDrive\Documents\Rhys Morgan Jones\My Projects\Coding\Python\Months\December 2016\aldi\till.py", line 151, in <module>
    start()
  File "C:\Users\rhysj\OneDrive\Documents\Rhys Morgan Jones\My Projects\Coding\Python\Months\December 2016\aldi\till.py", line 144, in start
    state = check_status(this_till-1)
  File "C:\Users\rhysj\OneDrive\Documents\Rhys Morgan Jones\My Projects\Coding\Python\Months\December 2016\aldi\till.py", line 58, in check_status
    status = check_file()
  File "C:\Users\rhysj\OneDrive\Documents\Rhys Morgan Jones\My Projects\Coding\Python\Months\December 2016\aldi\till.py", line 21, in check_file
    file[read-1][1] = f
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable.
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: What did you want `file[read-1][1]` to do? File objects are not indexable sequences. You certainly can't *assign* to them either.

Comment: it saves the line to an array

Comment: But `file` is not an array. It is a closed file object (you opened and closed it in `change_state()`, where `file` is a global name). Why is it global there in the first place?

Comment: Did you mean to use `f` instead perhaps?

Comment: this is the file array file = [[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,0]] at the start. file is an array f isn't

Comment: i get what your saying i've used file in the wrong place thanks